# Chrome: Override autocomplete=off for text field on web form

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autocomplete, extension

I regularly need to fill in a form on our intranet but the devs for an unknown reason have disabled autocomplete on some of the text fields. This means I have to repeatedly type in entries.

I have asked them to disable autocomplete=off but they are ignoring me.

Is there a way to  make the browser (Chrome) override the autocomplete=off so it can then remember my previously typed entries in an autocomplete selection list.

I have tried various extensions (Autofill, RoboForm) but I cant get them to do this somewhat simple thing. ChatGPT suggested I use the extension "Ignore X-Frame-Options Header" but still no luck

Comment: I believe there have been several security vulnerabilities/exploits that work using autocomplete. The devs are probably simply applying proper security practices.

Comment: No they are not because it is enabled on other string fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following Chrome extensions could help :

[**Force Autocomplete**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-autocomplete/piechbhjioolbecaioglhamjjjkmbchj?hl=en)

> Force autocomplete attribute in input fields to be on.
>
> Force "autocomplete" attribute in input fields to be "on". Allows form fields to remember what you typed the next time you re-visit them.

[**Always Autocomplete**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-autocomplete/djcfppnajkeijjkplclmeiddkefeaiel?hl=en)

> Changes webpage elements' autocomplete to be on. It helps you with
> enabling autofill feature for disabled web sites.
>
> This extension automatically changes webpage elements' autocomplete to
> be on. It helps you with enableing autofill feature for disabled web
> sites. E.g. A website doesn't want the browser to remember your user
> name and password, now you have a choice there.

I would suggest not enabling the extension when consulting
sensitive websites, such as your bank account.

Comment: Force Autocomplete is open-source and so simple you can understand how the entire thing works even if you don't know js well in under 5 minutes. I think it's safe to use even in sensitive contexts. https://github.com/numediaweb/nw_force_autocomplete

Comment: @ScottishTapWater It's possible they could have a "security" mechanism that detects changes to the page contents. Also, even if the extension is open source, you have to make sure the extension actually matches the source code, and that nothing malicious ever gets added.

Comment: The worst thing that could happen in that regard is that the bank would pop a message up asking you to disable your extensions... That being said, I'm constantly running exceptions that change page content and I've never encountered any issue...

Answer (score 5):

You can use any extension that enables scripting specific websites, such as [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pl), and use this or similar script:

```javascript
let fields = document.querySelectorAll('[autocomplete="off"]');

[...fields].forEach((field) => {
  field.removeAttribute('autocomplete');
});
```

This finds all elements with `autocomplete="off"` HTML and removes the attribute from them. You can limit the script to a specific URL with the `// @match` [metadata](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#@match) comment - e.g.:

```
// @match *.superuser.com/*
```

and also limit the HTML selector further if needed.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but I can't get it to work, when I inspect the HTML element it still shows autocomplete=off, although the Tampermonkey icon shows it has access to the site. My script is in next comment

Comment: `// ==UserScript==
// @name         AutoComplete On
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://<company>.net
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

let fields = document.querySelectorAll('[autocomplete="off"]');

[...fields].forEach((field) => {
  field.removeAttribute('autocomplete');
});`

Comment: Not too sure your matching is correct, that matches only the main domain, no subpages. Did you check if the script runs? You do that by checking the extension's icon next to address bar. It might also be that the values are added later. Hard to say without looking at the code of the webpage.